# VBA - infinite loop through 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I continue my project for company and have encountered new problem.

I made simple program thet loops through two columns - database of sales (sheet "Baza") and alphabetical list of customers with salesman's codename (Sheet "Statystyki"=. If  matching customer name in database has been found, the program should copy the salesman ID to the sheet with customer list.

The problem is, that after a dozen of loops, the program is looping to infinity and excel has to be closed.

```
'========================Uzupełnianie dostawców=================

Do Until LRowLista = LastRowLista

LRowLista = 6
LRow1 = 1
LRowPaste = 6

Rob:
        Klient = Cells(LRowLista, 1).Value
        If Len(Cells(LRowLista, 1)) = 0 Then
            ButtonChosen = MsgBox("Wykonano")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            GoTo Dalej
        End If
        
Dalej:  Do Until LRow1 = lastRow
Szukaj: LRow1 = LRow1 + 1
        Sheets("Baza").Activate
         If Len(Cells(LRow1, 1)) = 0 Then
            ButtonChosen = MsgBox("Zrobione")
            Exit Sub
         Else
            GoTo CzyKli
         End If
       
CzyKli:  If Cells(LRow1, 1).Value = Klient Then
            Cells(LRow1, 8).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Statystyki").Select
            Cells(LRowPaste, 2).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
            LRowPaste = LRowPaste + 1
            LRow1 = 1
            LRowLista = LRowLista + 1
            ButtonChosen = MsgBox("Uzupełniono")
            GoTo Rob
         Else
            GoTo Szukaj
         End If
        
    Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

Before this code there is simple code which makes alphabetical list of customers in "Statystyki" sheet from "Baza" sheet.

The program imports customer name from sheet 2 to a "Klient" string, then the loop starts searching through sheet 1 for first matching record. After finding it, the procedure of copying starts. Then, row number in sheet 1 loop is set to 1 and the program is loading next customer.

If I add a breakpoint ("ButtonChosen = MsgBox("Uzupełniono")" line in the code) after this procedure, the program works well, but wihout it, the program hangs out.

Any suggestions why it dont works properly wihout this breakpoint?

Comment: You should read up on avoiding select and avoiding using Goto as not recommended. It makes code hard to read and hard to debug.

Comment: I kindly refuse to review this code until it is refactored to contain no `goto`s.

Comment: Thank You for your advice! I used this method successfully in other parts of projects, f.ex. looping through multiple worksheets, but will learn about it.

Comment: By restructuring your Ifs you can remove all those Gotos and then you might even spot the problem yourself.

Comment: For some information behind *never use `GoTo`* https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/structured-programming/

Comment: Ok, I will try. I didnt have to worry about performance problems before, so I was not concerned about these GoTos, as long as it worked.